# setting a layout manager

Tags: java, layout

I want to have a frame that it has 9 planes with red and blue and green color and I set the frame as a borderlayout manager but it doesn't show anything.please help me.thanks
(the [`LightsNPlanesApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373481/3d-lights-planes) is correct and can be run correctly but the MainFrame is not correct because it doesn't show anything)

The MainFrame:(just the main method)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();

            addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

            pane.add(new LightsNPlanesApp(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            pane.add(new LightsNPlanesApp(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pane.add(new LightsNPlanesApp(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please remove anything from your code that is not necessary to reproduce your problem. It's quite difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: What part about creating a SSCCE to you not understand. You don't write 200 lines of code to test a new concept like using a layout manager. You write a program that first adds 1 component. Once you understand that you try adding a second component and so on. Learn to walk before you run and start listening to all the advice you've been given in the past.

Comment: I just put the LightNplanesApp here for more information.this panel will run correctly and will show 3 planes but I don't know that why the main Frame is not correct.all the things are OK .and because of this i put my panel here too.also sorry for putting  a lot of code here.

Comment: i want to put 3 panels with each other in the frame to have 9 planes but I can not please help me
thanks

Comment: When you run it does it show anything?

Comment: it just show a frame without those planes!

Answer (score 1):

```
add("Center", canvas3D);
```

... is obsolete / wrong and should be replaced with:

```
add(canvas3D, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

How does the code you posted compile? Did you bother to listen to my suggestion about starting with simple code? Is the problem with your custom JPanel or all JPanel'?

Why don't you try adding 3 JPanels each with a different background color and see if that works first. Of course if won't work, but once you figure out that problem, then maybe you can use the same solution on your other class.

Of course because you haven't posted a proper SSCCE, I'm just guessing which is why I'm not giving your what I think the solution is outright. If you are going to make use guess what the code thats causing the problem is like, then you will need to guess the solution as well given the hints provided. And again a SSCCE does not mean you include the full code from your custom panel, it means you post simple code that simulates the problem.